# Passing commandline argument after service installation using c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, installation

We had a problem with WCF hosting on service in Windows 2003.
We found a command line tool (httpcfg) which helped us to resolve the issue temporarily.

The following command line argument needs to run after the service installation:

```
httpcfg set urlacl -u http://+:8080/ -a "D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-490459244-4280451753-3120260354-1829)"
```

We need to pass this argument via installer using C#

That is via service controller after installer event. How would I do the same in C# using `ServiceController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

- Just run [`httpcfg.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) using [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)
- Use PInvoke to access the underlying Win32 API [`HttpSetServiceConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The second approach is a little messy but not that hard.  The PInvoke.net page describes the call and even gives a working example:

- [PInvoke.net: httpsetserviceconfiguration (httpapi)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/httpapi.httpsetserviceconfiguration)

***EDIT:** Some notes about cleanup issues inspired by Rob's comment. I put them here in this existing answer, because they don't make a good one on their own.*

Please note, that whatever approach you take (httpcfg.exe or direct use of the HTTP-API), make really sure that you unregister the URLs in your uninstall process.

The reason is, that HTTP.SYS (which actually is a kernel component) has only so much (nonpaged) memory available for managing URL reservations. If you exceed this, by having to many (possibly stale / left-over) registrations, you get errors and cannot register any new URLs (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824033).

While this is "solvable" by manually using httpcfg.exe to cleanup registrations you think(!) are orphaned (or allowing more memory - careful!) it is a royal pain and totally unnecessary, if uninstallers work as suggested.

Comment: Just a note to point out - don't forget to **undo** the action in your uninstaller! =)

Comment: Another note WRT the linked you provided for PInvoke (HttpSetServiceConfiguration). There is memory leak bug in that code. The `handleHash` variable in the `BindCertificate` method never deallocates the memory is allocates with `GCHandle.Alloc()`. Make sure to call `GCHandle.Free()`.